# creating multiple texts in certain x,y coordinates using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i've been trying a bit of web stuff over winter break, and i was thinking of creating a nonogram game, which should look like this:

[image: the way it should look]

i've had no problems creating the board and the logic etc, but at the point where i have all the numbers as lists of strings, i can't figure out a way of placing them nicely on top of and to the left of the cells like that, i don't want to hard code anything because the number of cells is a variable

i do have information on how big each cell is and where they are in terms of x,y values so if there was a way to render a text in an x,y coordinate i could probably have a loop to create them but i can't figure out how will this be done

thanks!

Comment: How is the board drawn? Is it a table? Is it on a canvas? A bit of background on the general structure would help.

Comment: it's drawn with a canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something close to this:

```
var baseYoffset = 100;
var baseXoffset = 100;
var cellWidth = 10;
var cellHeight= 10;
var columns   = 15;
var rows      = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < columns; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; i++){
        var num = document.createElement('div');
        num.style.position = 'absolute';
        num.style.top = baseYoffset + j * cellHeight + "px";
        num.style.left= baseXoffset + i * cellWidth + "px";
        num.innerHTML = numberList[i][j];
        document.body.appendChild(num);
    }
}
```

The `baseXoffset` and `baseYoffset` variables are the distance from the top and left of the page to the first cell. `cellWidth` and `cellHeight` are the width and height of the cells, and the `numberList` array contains the numbers in the list.